# SSRS – How to sum rounded amounts?

Tags: reporting-services, sum, rounding

In SSRS report I need to display an average balance per broker and an average balance for a company.

```
Average balance = total balance per day in month / nbr of days in month.
```

For broker average I have:

```
=Round(Sum(Fields!daily_balance.Value) / Fields!days_in_month.Value,2)
```

For a company I have the same of the total line:

```
=Round(Sum(Fields!daily_balance.Value) / Fields!days_in_month.Value,2)
```

The problem is that:

```
Round(balance1/days) + Round(balance2/days) not = round((balance1 + balance2)/days)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Why is that a problem? If you want to sum rounded amounts then don't round the sum of amounts but sum rounded amounts.

Comment: Assuming you mean you have several brokers per company and the sum of the averages does match at the company level.. If this is the issue then I have to agree with @WolfgangKais, there is nothing wrong and most consumers of reports will understand that. However, what I would do is NOT round the numbers but apply formatting to the cell/textbox instead (e.g. "f2" for 2 decimal places). That way, if you export the report to excel for example,the real numbers are stored in the workbook but formatted to 2 decimal places. So if you get queries you can reference those real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Always round in the end. Early rounding (in computer calculations) result in a increasing error propagation. Well for normal applications its hardly visible, but in measurement results in physics its a big thing to take care of.

And like `Alan` mentioned, just apply formating on a few decimal places, this way the real numbers are still stored.